# My website's favicon is not displayed in Bing search results

Tags: bing, favicon

My website has a problem with displaying the favicon in the output.
[image: SERP screen]
Even though I've practically done all the items from the recommendations https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/all/what-are-the-requirements-to-display-favicon-on/236d6598-41e2-483c-9950-aae8714d943c I just didn't do the last, fifth one: "5. The website must have a valid sitemap.xml file, and the sitemap should include the URL of the favicon file."

It seems to me it's not the best idea to add a link to the favicon in the sitemap. I'm not sure Google would like this.

I wrote on the Bing forum https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-bing/the-site-s-favicon-is-not-displayed-in-bing-search-results/m-p/3880129

But it's quiet there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a caching issue. It could take awhile to resolve. Be patient.

Note that Bing is insistent on requiring the `.ico` file extension. While Google will use whatever image you've setup even if it is a `.png|.gif`, similarly to how modern browsers can render the favicon even if it's not an `.ico`.

Once you've fixed things (if you need to). Utilize Bing webmaster tools;
https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/content-removal-broken-links-or-outdated-cache-cb6c294d

To instruct Bing to delete your old cached data, which will speed along the process of getting the updated page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried to clear the cache through the link you provided. However, it asks to mark content on the page that differs from what's cached. I don't have any, as the favicon is embedded in the code. I have another question regarding the .ico format. I have a favicon in this format in my website code: [https://tictactoefree.com/favicon.ico](https://tictactoefree.com/favicon.ico) But unfortunately it didn't help